# Manually Trigger Uploads with FineUploader on MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, fine-uploader

i'm trying to use FineUploader to be able to submit several files to the server on a single page using Asp-Net MVC 4. I'm using the code from the examples:

HTML:

```
<div id="manual-fine-uploader"></div>
<button id="triggerUpload" class="red text_only has_text" style="margin-top: 10px;">
       <span data-bind="text: 'Subir archivos'"></span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var manualuploader = $('#manual-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
                    debug: true,
                    request: {
                        element: $('#manual-fine-uploader'),
                        endpoint: "SaveArchivos"
                    },
                    autoUpload: false,
                    text: {
                        uploadButton: "<i class=\"icon-plus icon-white\"></i>"+i18n.t('seleccionarArchivos')
                    }
                });

                $('#triggerUpload').click(function() {
                    manualuploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
                });
            });
```

Controller:

```
    public class CondicionesComercialesController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpPost]
    public FineUploaderResult SaveArchivos(FineUpload upload)
    {
        // asp.net mvc will set extraParam1 and extraParam2 from the params object passed by Fine-Uploader

        var dir = @"e:\upload\path";
        var filePath = Path.Combine(dir, upload.Filename);
        try
        {
            upload.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new FineUploaderResult(false, error: ex.Message);
        }

        // the anonymous object in the result below will be convert to json and set back to the browser
        return new FineUploaderResult(true, new { extraInformation = 12345 });
    }
    ...
    }
```

The request gets to the server-side, but the upload parameter is always null. I guess i'm missing some id on the client-side but I can't find anything on the documentation that points out where to set it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the same exact example found at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/ASP.NET%20MVC%20C%23?

Comment: Yes the same classes.  I don't know if the js code is correct.

Comment: Have you stepped through the ModelBinder?  What are you seeing when the request hits the server?

Comment: You've nailed it. I was missing the ModelBinder line in the FineUpload class, my mistake. Now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please describe this a bit more, but this time, in an "answer"?, and then accept this answer?  I'd like others who run into the same problem to find this easily.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. I was missing the ModelBinder line in the FineUpload class (on server side):

```
    using System.IO;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Vizion.Web.UI.Helpers
    {

      [ModelBinder(typeof(ModelBinder))]

      public class FineUpload
      {
        ...
```

Now it works perfectly. Thanks to Ray Nicholus!

Comment: SO don't enable me to do it now. I've to wait until tomorrow to check it.